# Restaurar una máquina virtual en VMWARE

Tags: virtualización, vmware

Estaba ejecutando mi máquina virtual en VMware cuando de pronto mi pc dio el famoso pantallazo azul. Cuando se reinició mi pc e intenté volver a ejecutar mi máquina virtual ya no pudo iniciar, me marca error de disco desconocido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

, luego entra a una pantalla negra en un ciclo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me manda al boot

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se podría recuperar el inicio del disco para que pueda ejecutar de nuevo?

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade las trazas de error completas (o con más detalle).

Comment: Si claro @Alfabravo , ya añadí imágenes. Gracias

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes restaurar una máquina virtual a un estado anterior.

Seleccionas la Máquina virtual -> Snapshots.
Seleccionas el snapshot que quieras restaurar.
Haz clic en Restaurar.
Haz clic en Guardar para guardar un snapshot del estado actual antes de restaurar la máquina virtual al estado del snapshot seleccionado o elija No guardar para no guardar un snapshot.

Una vez restaurada, la máquina virtual adoptará el estado capturado en el snapshot seleccionado.